# Should the beginning_of_week return the first of the month if not the beginning of the week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

I'm trying to set some date variables for reporting, so I was experimenting with date calculations.

```
yesterday = DateTime.yesterday()
```

which is July 10, 2015

```
yesterday.beginning_of_week
```

returned July 5, 2015 which is last Sunday.

```
(yesterday.beginning_of_week - 1.days).beginning_of_week
```

returned July 1, 2015 which is the prior Wednesday.  This seems wrong.

```
(yesterday.beginning_of_week - 5.days).beginning_of_week
```

finally returned June 28, 2015.  Which is correct.

Should the first of the month automatically be the beginning of the week for some reason unknown to me?  Thanks...

EDIT -- MORE INFORMATION

```
Date.beginning_of_week
```

returns :monday

```
Date.new(2015, 7, 2).at_beginning_of_week
```

returns June 29, 2015, which is really expected for Monday.

Comment: I can't duplicate any of this; what's the value of `yesterday`? Of course, my weeks begin on Monday.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I added yesterday.  I was also looking at setting beginning of week to be Monday, but hadn't completed that yet.  I was surprised mine defaulted to Sunday as the docs seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: I still can't dupe using `b_o_w(:sunday)` for both `b_o_w`s.

Comment: @DaveNewton If I set yesterday to July 2, 2015, beginning of week still gives me July 1, 2015.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am on ActiveSupport 4.2.1.  What is your version?  By cannot duplicate, do  you mean you are getting the expected date of June 28, 2015?  Hmmm...

Comment: I was actually accidentally using a Rails 3 app, my bad :/ Under 4.2.1 I still can't dupe, although I'm still using `b_o_w(:sunday)` approach. When I config the app to use `:sunday` as b_o_w I still can't dupe; https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/5d66db2b9d7b594e8212

Comment: @DaveNewton See curious edits above.  bow is Monday and at_bow shows correct answer.

Comment: What version of Ruby? What's your TZ set to? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the week_of_month gem installed and it was giving me bad results.  I finally saw this in the backtrace.  Thanks @DaveNewton for your help because I wouldn't have looked for that if you hadn't said you weren't seeing those results.